# X goes black when using SimpleScreenRecorder

Tags: xorg

When using `SimpleScreenRecorder`, `X` goes black all the time when I do anything more trivial than typing in a terminal session. I have to switch to another `tty` and back to `X` for it to show again.

Does someone know a fix for this, or at least what is causing it?

EDIT: System info

```
Linux localhost 3.12.9-1-t520 #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jan 31 14:38:45 CET 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux
X.Org X Server 1.15.0
i3 version 4.7.2
SimpleScreenRecorder 0.1.2
```

Comment: Need more info: OS, version of SimpleScreenRecorder, desktop env. you're using, etc.

Comment: @sim: Added. Not using a desktop environment, only i3wm.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue that you might get resolved if you use the latest version from the project's Git repo. I found [this thread](http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/custom-codec-options/) with the following bit included:

> so now I am wondering how to install the glinject-next branch and use that. Sorry I am new to git and compiling so I don't know how to do it BUT really want to get keyint working because of this horrible black screen issue when restarting my stream at hitbox due to their cutting alogrythm and how my stream doesn't contain a keyframe every 2 seconds like they expect.

Looking at the Git repo the project looks to be fairly active, https://github.com/MaartenBaert/ssr. Directions for downloading, compiling, and installing are on the main page as well.

If that doesn't resolve your issue there's also a issue tracker on the Github page where you'll likely get better help than from us here in resolving your issue.

- https://github.com/MaartenBaert/ssr/issues

I did a quick search through the issue tracker and found no evidence of any prior tickets with this particular issue.

Comment: Sounds very similar although I'm not using gl. I'll test.

Comment: Same issue when using the git branch.